# mnotes package error: Incomplete \iffalse

Tags: untagged

I'm trying to use the [mnotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/mnotes?lang=en) package (`\usepackage{mnotes}`), which is a package for adding comments to the margins that point to text in the document.

but I'm getting this error:

```
(C:\ProgramsPortable\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\tex/latex/mnotes\mnotes.sty
)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 70.
<inserted text>
                \fi
```

I tried looking at the code in `mnotes.sty`, but I couldn't see any mismatched `\if`s or `\fi`s (as far I can see, though I'm no latex expert).

Turning on "basic" mode allows it to run, but functionality is greatly reduced:

```latex
\usepackage[basic]{mnotes}
```

Any ideas why this error is happening? Is the problem within mnotes or perhaps a dependency?

Comment: it is a bug in mnotes. It uses `\newif\ifoddpage` and if `\ifoddpage` is already defined (by loading the ifoddpage package before mnotes) this gives an unbalanced `\if` / `\fi`.

Answer (score 1):

I made a MWE to test this issue, and the problem went away! I started adding in lines one-by-one from my original tex file until the issue re-appeared.

MWE with no issues:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{mnotes}

\begin{document}
Hello world \MNOTE{This is an mnote} Goodbye
\end{document}
```

Once I added the line which imports algorithm2e (for pseudocode formatting), then it broke again. But **moving the mnotes import to be before algorithm2e fixes the problem** (Note: I didn't test whether the pseudocode still works), like so:

```
\usepackage{mnotes}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,vlined,figure,tworuled]{algorithm2e}
```

However, back in my original document, I moved the mnotes import to be the first line after `\documentclass` and my problem still occurrs.

Next I removed ALL the `\usepackage` lines in my original document and started adding them back in. It broke once I got to `\usepackage{ulem}`. Even though that package comes *after* `\usepackage{mnotes}`, it still conflicts.

**Conclusion: `mnotes` conflicts with other packages, if getting an error, remove other `\usepackage` lines until it works.**

Comment: don't add such info as answer. Edit your question, and put there an non-working example.

Comment: Thanks. It's fixed now.

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  We can try to find an answer for your problem so that you can still use `ulem`, but it would help if you edit your question to include a non-working example.

Comment: I'd be wary to use `mnotes`. In my experiments I found that it doesn't work properly with TeX Live 2017 on. Besides, it uses `\hoffset`, which is a bad thing.